# База вопросов в Андроид приложении

Tags: android, java

Привет. Мне необходимо написать приложение, где будут задаваться вопросы с вариантами ответов (тесты, короче говоря). Просто меня несколько озадачило, а где лучше хранить варианты ответов и собственно сами вопросы? Создать файл, использовать SQLlite, или даже в Strinq.xml (хотя кажется это самое не желательное).

Если использовать SQLlite, тогда скажите, пожалуйста, допустим, я сделаю `db.execSQL(yourSql)` и заполню БД своими вопросами, а вот откуда я буду эти вопросы брать, чтобы в БД их залить. Где их хранить изначально в таком случае. (Подключение к интернету не будет) :) Возможен ли вариант, чтоб при скачавании приложения, скачивался дамп, если да, то где об этом можно прочитать.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, исходя из вашего опыта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я решал аналогичную ситуацию так:

1. Кладем в res/xml некий XML файлик с вопросами
2. При первом запуске парсим XML и складываем вопросики в SQLite
3. Далее все время работаем с SQLite

Есть конечно и другой вариант:

1. создаем рученьками SQLite базу
       (благо клиентов в т.ч. гуйных
       много), кладем полученную базу в
       res/asset
2. При первом запуске копируем БД из ассетов в место по умолчанию (то что возвращается `Context.getDatabasePath()` - что-то навроде /data/data/[мой пакет]/databases
3. Далее все как обычно

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем загружать вопросы из XML в SQLite, если можно при необходимости получать их из XML? Есть какая-то причина?

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю делать в базе.
Нужны такие таблицы

```
"вопросы"
-id
-текст вопроса
-тип(один с многих, несколько с многих, да-нет)
-подсказка

"ответы"
-id
-id_вопроса
-текст_ответа
-правильный/неправильный
```

По id вопроса можно выбрать одним запросом ответы к нему и отобразить. Можно создать ещё одну таблицу "темы" и в таблицу вопросов прописывать номер темы. Если бы это были билеты, то тема могла быть бы "номером билета" (подразумевается, что в билете несколько вопросов).

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет. Вопросы и ответы будут изначально, если я сделаю в БД (насколько я понял Вы SQLlite имеете ввиду), то я изначально должен их туда вписать так как пользователь будет оттуда только читать, а не добавлять. Насколько я понял из документации, СГЛ лайт в основном используется, для хранения пользовательских настроек ?

Comment: Вы можете использовать базу (при этом и не одну) для хранения всего, чего Вам нужно. Пользовательские настройки - это просто одна из разновидностей данных приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Значится так: для хранения пользовательских настроек предпочтительно использовать встроенный механизм Setting-ов.
А вот как раз SQLite и предназначен для хранения нужной для работы приложения. Заполняется база при первом запуске приложения вообще без проблем: нужно в классе-наследнике SQLiteOpenHelper в методе `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` просто выполнить нужные SQL-инсерты через `db.execSQL(yourSql)` и все будет чотко.

Comment: Спасибо большое, тогда скажите, пожалуйста, мне еще вот что, допустим я сделаю db.execSQL(yourSql) и заполню БД своими вопросами, а вот откуда я буду эти вопросы брать чтобы в БД их залить. Где их хранить в таком случае. (Подключение к интернету не будет) :)

Comment: Возможно все. Как простой вариант просто прописывание в коде SQL-инструкций (константами) и их выполнять. Можно прописать вопросы в файле и его начитывать. Попробуйте для начала сделать константами

Comment: Как понять константами? Вопросов более 1000 допустим, ответов 4000. Создавать столько констант?

Comment: Ну я не думал, что у вас столько вопросов, честно. Вот и насоветовал константами

Comment: Я нисколько не сомневался в Вашей компетенции. Я очень благодарен, Вам, за то что помогаете! Тогда думаю, лучше создать файл со всеми вопросами и ответами. И во время первого запуска создавать табличку в которую из этого файла все вставлять?

Comment: Никто не мешает создать таблицу в своем удобном формате, можно даже в виде sqlite базы, которую при первом старте скачаете с интернета.

Есть ещё один способ доставить базу для приложения - просто делаете отдельное приложение, которое нужно установить (после установки можно сразу удалить) и оно установит базу (например на sdcard в условленное место).